# D3 - Tree of life plot not showing data

Tags: svg, d3.js, phylogeny

I am trying to add this phylogenetic tree view
https://observablehq.com/@d3/tree-of-life
into a dashboard. The full code is available there and linked on the page for download.

I can get my own data in and parsed. However, I can not get the tree to show.
Most specifically I do not understand where the `x` and `y` coordinates of the data points are set. It must be some implicit process?

```
function linkExtensionConstant(d) {
  return linkStep(d.target.x, d.target.y, d.target.x, innerRadius);
}

function _linkStep(){return(
function linkStep(startAngle, startRadius, endAngle, endRadius) {
  const c0 = Math.cos(startAngle = (startAngle - 90) / 180 * Math.PI);
  const s0 = Math.sin(startAngle);
  const c1 = Math.cos(endAngle = (endAngle - 90) / 180 * Math.PI);
  const s1 = Math.sin(endAngle);
  return "M" + startRadius * c0 + "," + startRadius * s0
      + (endAngle === startAngle ? "" : "A" + startRadius + "," + startRadius + " 0 0 " + (endAngle > startAngle ? 1 : 0) + " " + startRadius * c1 + "," + startRadius * s1)
      + "L" + endRadius * c1 + "," + endRadius * s1;
}
)}
```

Like above, the `d.target.x` is supposed to be set. However, when I run this `d.target.x` (and `y`) is `undefined`. I do not understand where in the code these attributes are attached to the items.
All that is set are `radius, length, depth` by the parsing function and later.

From my current understanding the code 'should' not work because the geometric transformation in `linkStep` that take in these parameters return `NaN` and hence the turtle path it creates is broken. Or the downloadable code might not be working? But unlikely and I guess its me...

Can anyone please have a look at try help me understand this lib?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. It is the `d3.cluster` function that assigns the coordinates. Still messing with it, but a step further now.